# images upload for conversion in c#

Tags: c#, image-uploading

I have this code which I use to convert a picture in order to be used in a POV Display. For some reason, it compiles successfully, but i dont get any output, i.e. the code for the converted picture is nowhere to be found.
I'm sure that i made a stupid mistake but i can't figure it out. I'd appreciate the help.

```
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length != 1) return;
             args[0] = @"C:\aaa.png";
            Image img = Image.FromFile (args[0]);           

            Bitmap bm = new Bitmap (img);           
            BitmapData bmd = bm.LockBits (new Rectangle (0, 0, img.Width, img.Height), 
                                          ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

            byte[,] ay = new byte[img.Width, img.Height];
            byte[] compactedAy = new byte[2 * img.Width];

            for (int y = 0; y < img.Height; y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < img.Width; x++) {
                    byte b = Marshal.ReadByte (bmd.Scan0, y * bmd.Stride + x * 4);

                    if (b == 0)
                        ay[x, y] = 1;
                    else
                        ay[x, y] = 0;

                    Console.Write (ay[x, y]);
                }

                Console.WriteLine ();
            }

            Console.Write ("byte dispArray[] = {");

            for (int x = 0; x < img.Width; x++) {
                if (x % 8 == 0) {
                    Console.WriteLine ();
                    Console.Write ("\t");
                }

                compactedAy[2 * x] = (byte)(ay[x, 0] << 7 | 
                                            ay[x, 1] << 6 | 
                                            ay[x, 2] << 5 | 
                                            ay[x, 3] << 4 | 
                                            ay[x, 4] << 3 | 
                                            ay[x, 5] << 2 | 
                                            ay[x, 6] << 1 | 
                                            ay[x, 7]);          

                compactedAy[2 * x + 1] = (byte)(ay[x, 8] << 7 | 
                                                ay[x, 9] << 6 | 
                                                ay[x, 10] << 5 | 
                                                ay[x, 11] << 4 | 
                                                ay[x, 12] << 3 | 
                                                ay[x, 13] << 2 | 
                                                ay[x, 14] << 1 | 
                                                ay[x, 15]);

                if (x < img.Width - 1) {
                    Console.Write ("{0,3} ", compactedAy[2 * x]);
                    Console.Write (", ");
                    Console.Write ("{0,3} ", compactedAy[2 * x + 1]);
                    Console.Write (", ");
                } else {
                    Console.Write ("{0,3} ", compactedAy[2 * x]);
                    Console.Write (", ");
                    Console.Write ("{0,3} ", compactedAy[2 * x + 1]);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine ();
            Console.WriteLine ("};");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what language / libraries are you using? Add those as tags and more people will be able to find your quesiton.

Comment: Thanks for the tip buddy, will do